# Error in is.data.frame(.data) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

Unable to  run this code and getting an error

```
#Crimes per years
    crime %>%
      filter(OCCURRED_ON_DATE < ymd("2018-12-21")) %>% 
      group_by(OCCURRED_ON_DATE)# %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = OCCURRED_ON_DATE, y = n)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = " Scatterplot Number of Incidents Reported in each year",
           y = 'Number of Incidents Reported',
           x = 'Date')
    
    Error in is.data.frame(.data) : 
      argument ".data" is missing,
```

with no default

Comment: You have a typo that is causing the error: `group_by(OCCURRED_ON_DATE)# %>%`, the `%>%` is commented out, so the next line `summarize(n = n())` has no data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `#` in line 3 of your code after `(OCCURRED_ON_DATE)`, shown below, which has commented out the subsequent `%>%`. This is causing the error.  Change

```
group_by(OCCURRED_ON_DATE)# %>%
```

to

```
group_by(OCCURRED_ON_DATE) %>%
```